# Android Fragmens with swipe examples

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

maybe someone have good android app example with fragments and swipe? I want to create app with this things, but i need example because i don't know how to work with this tecniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View Page flipper , with fragments and swipe event is working pretty good.
Please find the open source at - http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Android plugin can create such an example project for you if you build with a newer API (API level 15 or above I think).

You should have put a minimal effort of googeling your question first, though. As you surely have noticed by now it's not too popular to ask questions you very easily can find an answer to on your own.